# Shell script returns -1 as execution status while passing arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, jclouds

I am trying to copy a script to one VM using jclouds SSH utility.
Below is my script:

## Java Code:

```
String filename = getKey().toLowerCase() + ".sh";
script = Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
ssh.put("/tmp/" + filename, script);



    if(failure.equalsIgnoreCase("killprocesses")){
        String processToKill = getProcessName();
         response = ssh.exec("/bin/bash /tmp/" + filename + " " + processToKill);
        }
```

## Killprocesses.sh File

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script for KillProcesses Chaos Monkey
var1=$1
cat << EOF > /tmp/kill_loop.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
    pkill -KILL -f $var1;
    sleep 1
done
EOF

nohup /bin/bash /tmp/kill_loop.sh &
```

Killprocesses.sh file takes argument from java code. It returns the below error after execution.

```
org.jclouds.ssh.SshException: bad status -1 ExecResponse(command=[/bin/bash /tmp/killprocesses.sh python])
at org.jclouds.ssh.jsch.JschSshClient$ExecConnection.create(JschSshClient.java:426)
at org.jclouds.ssh.jsch.JschSshClient$ExecConnection.create(JschSshClient.java:397)
at org.jclouds.ssh.jsch.JschSshClient.acquire(JschSshClient.java:177)
```

If I hardcode the argument in the shell script, it doesnt throw any error. 
Please could any one help me understand what diff it makes to exit status if I pass as argument.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the arguments?

Comment: I can see the argument is passed correctly.This is part of error I receive " ExecResponse(command=[/bin/bash /tmp/killprocesses.sh python])" . In this "python" is the argument that i passed.

Comment: If you run the script manually like that, do you notice any error? Could there be any permission issues ?